# Ranking results of sql query resultset

Tags: php, sql

I want to rank the results of a SQL query resultset according to some conditions:

- Occurrences of keyword
- First match keyword to title then company name then another column and so on..
- If keyword matches into more than 2 columns in a particular row then preference/higher rank should be given to that row

FULL TEXT-AGAINST pair can be used for single column but can't satisfy all conditions.
If there is any way then please share.

Now I'm using this after some suggested answers:

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b, %Y')AS dt, 
                        case when title LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' then 6 else 0 end +
                        case when description LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' then 3 else 0 end +
                        case when Channel_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' then 1 else 0 end +
                        case when Industry_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' then 1 else 0 end +
                        case when Company_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' then 1 else 0 end as score FROM Search
WHERE title LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' or
Channel_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%'  or
Company_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%'  or
description LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%' or
Industry_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%') scored order by score desc
```

Comment: Replace your `... where à union ... b` with `... where a or b`, then you can order your rows by a calculated weight.

Comment: As to "occurrences of keyword": So if I look for a string and it occurs once in `Industry_Name` and twice in `Platform_Name`, that makes a count of 3. Yes?

Comment: By the way: You do know that `title like '%and%'` will not only match `'this and that'` but also `'Sandy beach'` and want it this way, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work well for very big tables, but will give you a starting point:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b, %Y') AS dt,  
IF(title LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%', 1, 0) + 
IF(Channel_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%', 2, 0) +
IF(Company_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%', 1, 0) +
IF(Industry_Name LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%', 1, 0) + 
...
IF(Platform_Description LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%', 1, 0) as score
FROM Search
) scored_results
WHERE score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The score>0 can be replaced by a different threshold.

The 1,0 numbers in the IF(condition, 1, 0) can be replaced by other scoring, even negative. For example: IF(Title like '%foo%', 10, -5)

Comment: Thanks @Y.L it gave me a good idea, but the problem is this query returning all rows from the table, I just need matching results.

Answer (score 1):

I think logic like this encapsulates your conditions:

```
SELECT s.*, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b, %Y') AS dt
FROM Search s
WHERE CONCAT_WS(':', title, channel_name, . . . ) LIKE '%".$fkeyword."%'
ORDER BY (LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(':', title, channel_name, . . . ), $fkeyword, CONCAT($fkeyword, 'x'))
                ) -
          LENGTH(CONCAT_WS(':', title, channel_name, . . . ))
         ) DESC,
         INSTR(CONCAT_WS(':', title, channel_name, . . . ), $fkeyword);
```

I would strongly recommend that you relax your conditions and implement a full text search instead.